# Qlik Sense - GetfieldSelections

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

sum({$<[Category Parent]={GetfieldSelections([Category Parent])}>}Revenue)

This is not working in Qliksense. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum({$<[Category Parent]={'$(=GetfieldSelections([Category Parent]))'}>}Revenue)
```